# Ubuntu 17.10 duplicate pycharms

Tags: 17.10, pycharm

I have 2 versions of pycharm installed on ubuntu 17.10 - 1 of them is installed via Software. The other, which i'm trying to remove, I have 0 clue as to where it came from. A bit of a newb question, so apologies in advance, but any advice would be greatly appreciated as to what I can do to remove it.

Comment: Open terminal and run `snap list`, what's the output?

Comment: yep,'pycharm-community' is there

Answer (score 0):

It may be a snap package you have installed. To verify run `snap list` in Terminal and look for any entry related to `pycharm` (for example `pycharm-community`).

To remove it simply run

```
snap remove pycharm-community
```